# How to download a file name starting with "xyz" from server in Spring integration ftp?

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

FTP inbound XML configuration:

```xml
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
            channel="ftpChannel"
            session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
            filename-pattern="*.*"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            remote-directory="/server/"
            local-directory="${localDir}"
            preserve-timestamp="false">
```

How to  download a file name starting with "xyz" from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the pattern to match: `filename-pattern="xyz*"`; youe existing pattern matches all files with a `.` somewhere in the name.